# Writing a unit test for gcm

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-espresso

I want to write a unit test that starts the test when a message is received at my `GcmListenerService`,I tried to bind to the the `GcmListenerService` but it is not possible because `GcmListenerService` overrides `onBind` with such that the method can't be overridden.
starting the service from my test doesn't make sense because I want it bo be invoked when a message is received from the server.
any ideas ?

Comment: I have created a ServiceRule and tried to start the service manually,but this is not the right way to do it because onMessageReceived is never called this way.I wanted to bind to GcmListenerService  but this is also not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution by creating a `GCMListenerService`  object,I hope this is the right way.

```
public class mytest{


    private GCMListenerService mReceiver;
    private Context context;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
        mReceiver=new GCMListenerService(context);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGPS() {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("message", Constants.GET_LOCATION);
        mReceiver.onMessageReceived("maxim",bundle);
    }

}
```